# Application for remodel project diagrams?

Tags: diagrams

Trying to find an easy to use application for making diagrams. The application will be used for drawings of remodel projects, so mainly decks and houses. I am trying to help a novice Mac user who just received his contractor's license find a simple draw program that will work for simple diagrams.

Answer (score 0):

Is Google Sketchup too complex? http://sketchup.google.com/ seems ideal if they can cope with the 3D part

Comment: Google Sketchup seems perfect. I just went fthrough some of the tutorials that come with it and beyond the four initial tutorials there are 24 others that are specific to lines, rectangles, etc. This is just what the contractor needs and can learn features as needed. Perfect.

Comment: I'm glad you like it. Several friends really like to use it, one did use it for building work. If answers seems okay, it is normal for the person who asks a question to accept an answer. That gives the person who gave the answer a bit of 'reputation', and also tells others that the question is answered, which saves them a little effort. Of course, if you want more help now, just ask. Or ask a new question in the future.

Answer (score 0):

[Google Sketchup](http://sketchup.google.com/) might be nice if you're doing remodeling. It's a pretty simple and free program that lets you build 3d models of houses, decks and the like, and it has a better learning curve in my opinion than big commercial modeling programs.

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestion! I downloaded the free version and tutorials. Very impressive and the tutorials make the learning curve less steep.